# How to do something like Assertions.assertAllFalse()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertion

I'm using `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;` for unit testing and I have to assert for many items if they are false. For instance:

```java
boolean item1 = false;
boolean item2 = false;
boolean item3 = false;
boolean item4 = false;

// is something like this possible
Assertions.assertAllFalse(item1, item2, item3, item4);
```

What method should I use and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the number of your values, easiest (IMHO) would be to simply write it out as a logical expression:

```java
Assertions.assertThat(item1 || item2 || item3 || item4).isFalse();
Assertions.assertThat(!(item1 && item2 && item3 && item4)).isTrue();
```

If one of your boolean values is true, the test will fail.

Or, if you do not know the number of values beforehand, [iterable and array assertions](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-group-assertions) might be of help:

```java
final List<Boolean> bools = …; // e.g. List.of(item1, item2, item3, item4)
Assertions.assertThat(bools).containsOnly(false);
Assertions.assertThat(bools).doesNotContain(true);
Assertions.assertThat(bools).allMatch(b -> !b);
Assertions.assertThat(bools).noneMatch(b -> b);
```

Or you might even use plain Java streams to express your expectation:

```java
final List<Boolean> bools = …; // e.g. List.of(item1, item2, item3, item4)
Assertions.assertThat(bools.stream().filter(b -> b).count()).isEqualTo(0);
Assertions.assertThat(bools.stream().allMatch(b -> !b)).isTrue();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement your own method for that:

```
@Test
public void test(){
  assertAllFalse(true, true, false);
}

public void assertAllFalse(Boolean... conditions){
  List.of(conditions).forEach(Assert::assertFalse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `assertFalse(item1 || item2 || item3 || item4)`.

Comment: @Abel de Bruijn: Good to hear! :) Thanks for the feedback! Feel free to mark one of the answers as accepted, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers